# Google Sheets: Have a formula change a cell only once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write an IF statement that stops once its criterion has been met. Essentially, I want to be able to replace the cells that it's referencing with new information without it reverting back to being FALSE again. Once it comes up TRUE once, I just want it to... stop running the IF statement and stay static. Thank you!

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample *with no sensitive data* so that we can visualise better what you are trying to achieve? Thanks !